# Weka Filter class is not found

Tags: java, class, weka

Writing code on Eclipse with Weka. Trying to use the weka.filters.Filter method but I constantly receive this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/filters/Filter

Everything else seems to be imported right and I see the filter class in the Package Exploration.

Thank you to everyone in advance

Comment: How did you add the Weka dependency? Simply linking to a jar or via Maven/Gradle dependency?

Comment: added eternal Jar through the project's properties

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Eclipse in a long time, as I prefer [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Here is what I did:

1. Create a new workspace
2. Create a new *Java project*
3. Unchecked *Create module-info.java* and clicked on *Next*

[image]

4. Added my external *weka.jar* under *Classpath* and clicked on *Finish*:

[image]

5. Created class `Testing.java` in package `myweka` with this content:

```java
package myweka;

import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.MultiFilter;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Filter f = new MultiFilter();
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Here it is what it looks like in Eclipse:

[image]

6. Executed the class without problems (just outputs the classname in the console).

Comment: thank you, but nothing changed. How would you do that with IntelliJ? This error about the Filter class keep popping up

Comment: I only use Maven as build system, I don't create projects where I just add jars.

Comment: Furthermore, these steps were executed on a new, empty workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply adding an external jar to your project, you could set up a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new directory to house all your code
2. Create a file called `pom.xml` ([Maven **P**roject **O**bject **M**odel](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)) and add this content (the libraries that are required for the project are listed inside the `dependencies` tag, this example uses Weka 3.9.5; the 3.8.5 dependency is commented out; you can only use either or):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyWeka</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyWeka</name>
  <description>Project using Weka.</description>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Weka 3.9.5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
      <artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Weka 3.8.5 -->
    <!--dependency>
      <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
      <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.5</version>
    </dependency-->
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

3. Create directory `src/main/java/myweka` in the same directory as the `pom.xml` file.
4. Place the following content as `Testing.java` in that directory:

```java
package myweka;

import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.MultiFilter;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Filter f = new MultiFilter();
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

5. Launch Eclipse and create a new workspace.
6. Import your project

[image]

7. Import the project as an *Existing Maven Project*

[image]

8. Select the directory where your `pom.xml` is located and click on *Finish*.

[image]

9. Once Eclipse has finished the import, you can execute the `myweka.Testing` class, which will just output the filter's classname in the console.